# Ext.JS Prevent Proxy from sending extra fields

Tags: json, extjs, tree, extjs4

Here is my model:

```
Ext.define('A.model.Group', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:['id', 'name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/group',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false
        }
    }
});
```

The model is being used in a Tree via a TreeStore

The problem is that when a `PUT`, `POST` or `DELETE` method is done, instead of sending only fields from the model in the JSON payload, fields from `Ext.data.NodeInterface` are also sent. Here is an example payload:

```
{"id":"","name":"TestGroup","parentId":"8","index":0,"depth":3,"checked":null}
```

I don't want the extra fields `parentId`, `index`, `depth`, and `checked` to be sent. What is the best way to do this? I don't want to have to ignore them on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wan't to send only specific data to server, writeAllFields is not the solution as if is set to false it only sends the modified fields. 
The solution for your problem is defining your own writer and overriding the method `getRecordData` here is a posible example:

```
var newWriter = Ext.create('Ext.data.writer.Json',{
  getRecordData: function(record){
       return {'id':record.data.id,'name':record.data.name};
  }
})

Ext.define('A.model.Group', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:['id', 'name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/group',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: newWriter
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

the `NodeInterface` adds these fields into your model:

```
{name: 'parentId',   type: idType,    defaultValue: null},
{name: 'index',      type: 'int',     defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'depth',      type: 'int',     defaultValue: 0, persist: false},
{name: 'expanded',   type: 'bool',    defaultValue: false, persist: false},
{name: 'expandable', type: 'bool',    defaultValue: true, persist: false},
{name: 'checked',    type: 'auto',    defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'leaf',       type: 'bool',    defaultValue: false},
{name: 'cls',        type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'iconCls',    type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'icon',       type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'root',       type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false, persist: false},
{name: 'isLast',     type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false, persist: false},
{name: 'isFirst',    type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false, persist: false},
{name: 'allowDrop',  type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, persist: false},
{name: 'allowDrag',  type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, persist: false},
{name: 'loaded',     type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false, persist: false},
{name: 'loading',    type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false, persist: false},
{name: 'href',       type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'hrefTarget', type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'qtip',       type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'qtitle',     type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: false},
{name: 'children',   type: 'auto',   defaultValue: null, persist: false}
```

two of them dont have `persist' property.

Most of NodeInterface's fields default to persist: false. This means they are non-persistent fields by default. Non-persistent fields will not be saved via the Proxy when calling the TreeStore's sync method or calling save() on the Model. In most cases, the majority of these fields can be left at their default persistence setting, but there are cases where it is necessary to override the persistence of some fields. The following example demonstrates how to override the persistence of a NodeInterface field. When overriding a NodeInterface field it is important to only change the persist property. name, type, and defaultValue should never be changed.
Override the fields like this:

```
 { name: 'iconCls', type: 'string',  defaultValue: null, persist: true },
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution since it is only using configs and does not need to override lowlevel functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a serializer to the fields in the model you do not want to send to the server.

```
var makeUndefined = function(value, record) {
    return undefined;
}

var fieldsOfYourModel = [
    {
        serialize: makeUndefined,
        name: 'parentId'
    },
    {
        serialize: makeUndefined,
        name: 'index'
    }
];
```

`serialize` is a function which converts the Model's value for this Field into a form which can be used by whatever Writer is being used to sync data with the server. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-serialize

`serialize` is available since Ext JS 4.1.1.

Comment: Excellent solution!  You imply this but don't say it explicitly (and it wasn't intuitive to me): if the serialize method returns undefined that field is excluded from submission to the server entirely (it doesn't submit `undefined` or the like)