# Ext JS Store POST request filter params

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I have a Store configured with a proxy to `POST` data to the server. I add records to this store dynamically. After calling the `sync()` method on the store the data gets sent to the server. But looking at the network traffic I see that the whole records data is sent. How can I configure the store to send only individual data (like only IDs of the record)?

I have tried seeting the `WriteAllFields` property to false on the JSON writter connected to the proxy but this did not help

I have also tried this approach: [Ext.JS Prevent Proxy from sending extra fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003975/ext-js-prevent-proxy-from-sending-extra-fields) but the request was not even performed

```
var documentStore = Ext.getStore('Document');
var trashStore = Ext.getStore('TrashDocuments');

documentStore.each (function(record) {

    console.debug(record);

    //record.phantom = true;
    //record.setDirty();

    trashStore.add(record);
    documentStore.remove(record);
});


var newWriter = Ext.create('Ext.data.writer.Json',{
  getRecordData: function(record){
       return {'id':record.data.id};
  }
});

trashStore.getProxy().setWritter(newWritter);

trashStore.sync({
            success: function()
            {
                console.debug("success!!");
            },
            failure: function()
            {
                console.debug("failed...");
            },
            callback: function()
            {
                console.debug("calling callback");
            },
            scope: this
        });

console.debug("END");
```

Comment: How are you modifying the record? Are you by any chance setting the dirty flag on it?

Comment: I add the records to this store from another store and than call sync()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`writeAllFields`** config is not working because that is only meaningful for non-phantom records; any fields of a phantom (new) record will be viewed as "changed" and therefore included in the request packet.

To exclude specific fields from being included in the request, add **[persist:false](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-persist)** to the fields you don't want to include.

That being said, I don't quite understand why you'd only want to write the ids of a newly added record. Unless you are explicitly having Ext JS create those ids for you, what are you actually going to be sending to server? I don't know your use case, but typically it is desirable to have your persistence layer (e.g., a database) assign identifiers to your records.

Comment: But you know those IDs are dynamically generated for new model instances, right? Are you using one of the Ext.data.IdGenerator subclasses?

Comment: They are not  generated I know them because I have added them from another exsisting store.

Comment: Ok, that would have been good information to include in your original post :) Instead of trying to hack together a writer to do this, why not just collect() the ids from the store and post them via Ext.Ajax?

Comment: I actually ended up writting an Ajax request which took 5 minutes. Thanks for the advice anyway...